# Is there an equivalent to ssh-copy-id with OpenSSH in Powershell?

Tags: ssh, powershell, openssh

I'm using PowerShell and have OpenSSH 4.6 installed. I'd like to use ssh-copy-id so I can login using a key without doing through the manual process of copying keys to servers. Is there an equivalent to the linux command ssh-copy-id that can be used or is there a PowerShell script already created somewhere that does this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/224810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ssh-copy-id-for-windows/224851#224851

Comment: Oh, thanks. Shouldn't have stuck the problem to PowerShell as that negated the proper answer.

Comment: Their might be a way to do it that is more idiomatically powershell.  Though the bulk of what is being done is on the server site.  I believe I saw a .NET SSH client somewhere at one point in time, so you might be able to avoid using plink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was on similar quest and seems like I've gone a bit overboard. You can find the powershell script here: https://github.com/VijayS1/Scripts/blob/master/ssh-copy-id/ssh-copy-id.ps1